# ERROR Android manifest : Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > Android resource linking failed

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am receiving this error when trying to build an app using react native using google maps. the error came about after editing the android manifest to include the API key.
This is the error

```
C:\Users\x0zon\Documents\CPTR405\carbooking>react-native run-android
info Starting JS server...
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug)...
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  C:\Users\x0zon\Documents\CPTR405\carbooking\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:34: AAPT: error: attribute android:configchanges not found.

  C:\Users\x0zon\Documents\CPTR405\carbooking\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:34: AAPT: error: attribute android:windowsoftinputmode not found.

  error: failed processing manifest.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
23 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 22 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

this is the Android Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  package="com.carbooking">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" 
        android:value="API key intentionally removed />
      <activity 
        android:name=".MainActivity" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configchanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" 
        android:windowsoftinputmode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am new to react and android studio and i have tried some solutions related to making changes to the gradle version in build.gradle and i have classmates using the same android manifest file with no issues. I am lost and confused.

Comment: Try to clean project using following command  cn android && ./gradlew clean